# Why was closed as "non-constructive" removed?

Tags: discussion, close-reasons

When I used to be active on the site at the beginning (around two years ago) many questions were closed as "not constructive." When I recently came back I noticed this was no longer the case. Was "not constructive" removed because it wasn't actually a reason, or was it simply replaced with better reasons?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The rationale for changing the close reasons, and the implementation of the "on hold" waiting period are explained in [this Meta post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/184154/closing-changes-on-hold-unclear-too-broad-opinion-based-off-topic-reasons).